# Thunderbird: specify handler for opening file and arguments

Tags: application, thunderbird, file-associations

In Thunderbird, I can set handler for opening files for given extension.

```
Preferences
    -> Attachements
```

I have specified I want to use `/usr/bin/mpv` for opening `wav` files. And I see that my preference has been saved in  my profiles directory in `handlers.json`:

```
"audio/x-wav":{"action":2,"extensions":["wav"],"handlers":[{"name":"mpv","path":"/usr/bin/mpv"}]}},"schemes":{}}
```

But I also need to specify commandline arguments to use, when opening with `mpv`:

Thunderbird tries to open file as

```
mpv file.wav
```

instead, I need the file to be opened as:

```
mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui file.wav
```

How can I tell Thunderbird to use commandline arguments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox/Thunderbird cannot pass arguments to commands.

Create an extra script instead, e.g.

```bsh
$ cat mpvp
#! /bin/bash
mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui "$@"
```